# RoR 4.2 <module:Plugins> Airbrake is not a module (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Досталось от другого программиста приложение. При запуске сервера ruby on rails выпадает подобный список ошибок:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/delayed-plugins-airbrake-1.1.0/lib/delayed-plugins-airbrake/version.rb:3:in `<module:Plugins>': Airbrake is not a module (TypeError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/delayed-plugins-airbrake-1.1.0/lib/delayed-plugins-airbrake/version.rb:2:in `<module:Delayed>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/delayed-plugins-airbrake-1.1.0/lib/delayed-plugins-airbrake/version.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/activesupport-4.2.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/delayed-plugins-airbrake-1.1.0/lib/delayed-plugins-airbrake.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /home/posit_production/www/site.ru/releases/20160601144746/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:45:in `block in exec_app_rails'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:34:in `exec_app_rails'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/lib/rails/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/bin/rails:9:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@site.ru/gems/railties-4.2.7/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:16:in `load'
from bin/rails:16:in `<main>'
```

В конфиге Gemfile есть такое:

```
gem 'airbrake'
gem 'delayed-plugins-airbrake'
```

Если убрать обе строки - то, ошибка получается такой:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- delayed-plugins-airbrake (LoadError)
```

Никак не могу понять, в чем дело. С чего начинать и в какую сторону смотреть...

версия Руби - 2.1.2
версия рельс - 4.2.7

Comment: А вы сами насколько владеете Ruby и Rails? Если не владеете, то придётся либо срочно осваивать, либо отказываться от задачи. А если владеете, то берите отладчик и осматривайте, где происходит взрыв.

Comment: Я никогда не ставил подобных гемов. И не знаю что они делают в проекте...  Пытаюсь отключить, но как я уже написал - ошибки лишь меняются... Руби я знаю, рельсы знаю, как фреймворк.

Comment: Ну ёлки-палки, поиск по "airbrake rails" мгновенно показывает, что это такое и для чего надо. Если при убирании гемов появляются другие ошибки, значит, есть использующий их код, и надо либо убирать и его, либо возвращать гемы обратно. Отладка целых чужих приложений здесь оффтопик.

Comment: А никто гемы и не убирал ). Проблема в том, что в любом случае при наличии гема или без него - ошибка все равно хочет этот гем ). Документацию по этому гему я видел, но либо он стоит тут криво, либо для деплоя его никогда не использовали... Но и на том спасибо... Как бы, если даже гуглить эту ошибку - есть темы на стековерфлоу, но они проблему не решают

Comment: Ну как это не убирал, сами же пишете, что из `Gemfile` пробовали убрать эти два гема :)

Comment: пробовал, сразу после того, как сервер на это ругнулся...

Comment: Странные у вас способы ликвидации проблемы. "М, печень отказала? Давайте уберём, может заработает". Я утрирую, но этот подход тоже пугает о_О

Comment: Мне нужен код приложения, а не этот гем. Понимаете? Мне бы запустить сервер... Пока выглядит так, что печень не работала с самого начала, а мешает ей запускаться комок какой-то херни в горле... Ну не надо мне разбираться с этим гемом, моя задача сейчас ЗАПУСТИТЬ приложение. То есть, убрать по максимуму все зависимости... ((

Comment: Понимаю. Но код приложения ваш и у вас, отлаживать его можете только вы сами. Если вы считаете, что эти гемы прикручены "сбоку", то, в переносном смысле, "откручивайте винтики по одному и после каждого смотрите, на чём ещё держится". Т. е. выпиливайте строчку за строчкой, ссылающиеся на эти библиотеки, выявляя нужные по стектрейсу, пока стектрейсы не перестанут возникать. Если в результате от приложения ничего не останется, значит, оно прикручено не сбоку :Р

Comment: Спасибо )). Этим пока и занимаюсь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле, всё просто. Этот странный гем `delayed-plugins-airbrake` не обновлялся с декабря 2013 года. За это время (примерно пол года назад) успела выйти 5-я версия `airbrake`. В контексте вопроса, нам интересно что она "из коробки" умеет обрабатывать ошибки `DelayedJob`. И в ней определён **класс** `Delayed::Plugins::Airbrake`. В `delayed-plugins-airbrake` же определён **модуль** с таким же именем. Интерпретатор видит обоих при инициализации приложения и выдаёт соответствующую ошибку.
Подозреваю, что случайно был выполнен `bundle update` который и обновил `airbrake` до версии 5+. Проверить это можно в репозитории, в файле `Gemfile.lock`, (если в него ещё не было коммита).

Возможные решения:

1. Удалить `delayed-plugins-airbrake` и все его упоминания из кода и выполнить `bundle install`.
2. Откатить `Gemfile` и `Gemfile.lock` до стабильного состояния, сделать `bundle install` и впреть аккуратнее работать с обновлением.

Мне, лично, больше нравится первый вариант, но нужно тщательно проверить работу с новой версией.

Comment: Да, спасибо, похоже на правду.